# scipy.io.wavfile.write does not work when I write to a file with the same filename as a previously deleted file

Tags: python, scipy, wav

When I use wavfile.write() with a filename that I previously used but deleted, instead of writing the wav file with the newly recorded audio, it seems to resurrect the deleted file.  This happens even if I record in a different directory.  For example if I at one point had a file '/Users/folder1/test.wav', deleted this recording and then recorded a new file '/Users/folder2/test.wav', this new recording is of the audio I had deleted.  Now, if I just use a new filename entirely there's no problem.  Can anyone tell me what's happening?

```py
_, data = record()
wavfile.write('/Users/folder1/test.wav', RATE, data)
```

```py
def record():
    """
    Record a word or words from the microphone and 
    return the data as an array of signed shorts.

    Normalizes the audio, trims silence from the 
    start and end, and pads with 0.5 seconds of 
    blank sound to make sure VLC et al can play 
    it without getting chopped off.
    """
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=RATE,
        input=True, output=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE)

    num_silent = 0
    snd_started = False

    r = array('h')

    while 1:
        # little endian, signed short
        snd_data = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
        if byteorder == 'big':
            snd_data.byteswap()
        r.extend(snd_data)

        silent = is_silent(snd_data)

        if silent and snd_started:
            num_silent += 1
        elif not silent and not snd_started:
            snd_started = True

        if snd_started and num_silent > 30:
            break

    sample_width = p.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


    r = normalize(r)
    r = trim(r)
    r = add_silence(r, 0.5)
    return sample_width, np.asarray(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a fool... The problem was with iTunes, not with the code. Thanks to everyone who looked at this.